# moving data in a pandas dataframe after a certain fixed column over to the next set of rows repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have no idea how to even approach this problem. I have a pandas dataframe let's say with 2 rows only any many columns many of which are repeating as following:

```
      A   B   C  D    A   B   C   D ...
hel   1   3   5  9    1   3   5   8
good  1   6   5  8    2   4   5   8
```

What I want to do is move all the constantly repeating 2nd set of columns over to the next set of rows as so...

```
      A   B   C  D    
hel   1   3   5  9    
good  1   6   5  8 
hel   1   3   5  8
good  2   4   5  8
```

Of course this is a tiny sample there are way more columns that are constantly repeating for every X columns...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df.columns = [df.columns, df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).cumcount()]
print(df.stack(level=1).droplevel(level=1))
```

Prints:

```
      A  B  C  D
hel   1  3  5  9
hel   1  3  5  8
good  1  6  5  8
good  2  4  5  8
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
      A  B  C  D  A  B  C  D
hel   1  3  5  9  1  3  5  8
good  1  6  5  8  2  4  5  8
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of your solution. Could you explain with a bit more detail as to whats happening in the code?

Comment: @JesseSealand with `df.columns = [df.columns, df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).cumcount()]` I add second column level `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1`. Then I use stack to move this column index level to row index level (this operation creates the final shape). Then I discard this row index level.

Comment: @Andrei Kesely, maybe I am not following something. When I try this I get: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6205 elements, new values have 2 elements. Any idea why? Also, where in your code are you indicating to go to the next row after the pattern columns repeat?

Answer (score 2):

one option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.pivot_longer(ignore_index=False, names_to = '.value', names_pattern='(.)')
      A  B  C  D
hel   1  3  5  9
good  1  6  5  8
hel   1  3  5  8
good  2  4  5  8
```

An alternative, relying on numpy, as well as the fact that your columns are repeating in a clearly defined manner:

```py
uniqs = df.columns.unique()
arr = df.to_numpy().reshape((-1, uniqs.size))
index_count = uniqs.size//df.index.size
pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=uniqs, index = df.index.repeat(index_count))
      A  B  C  D
hel   1  3  5  9
hel   1  3  5  8
good  1  6  5  8
good  2  4  5  8
```